# Possible to suppress error messages with a custom error message | PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was wondering if it is possible to suppress an error message with my own error message.

If my input exceeds a certain int value, I get a foreign key violation. I would like to present this message with my own information.

i.e:
current: ERROR: insert or update on table "flightplan" violates foreign key constraint "fk_flightplan_airline"
My message: The value you entered violates the foreign key relationship. Please check your entry and try again.

I thought that "THEN raise EXCEPTION" would help, but it didn't.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_flight(
  PLAN_ID INT,
  AIRLINE_ID INT,
  STATUS_ID INT)
  RETURNS void AS $BODY$
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO flight.flightplan
  VALUES(
    PLAN_ID,
    AIRLINE_ID,
    STATUS_ID);
  IF airline_id > 8 THEN raise EXCEPTION 'The value you entered violates the foreign key relationship. Please check your entry and try again';
  ELSE raise notice 'Worked!';
  END IF;
  END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


SELECT add_flight(1, 9, 3); -- ERROR: insert or update on table "xy" violates foreign key constraint "fk_xy"
                            -- but here I need my own Message to show up
```

Is it even possible to do something like this?

Comment: See [Trapping errors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.